# Update column of current row

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I'm looping through contacts, pulling out specific data then want to update a particular column on the current row. How can I do that?

The line is at the very bottom, I just want to change it from a 0 to 1.

```
    require('../mailin.php');
    $mailin = new Mailin("https://api.sendinblue.com/v2.0","Your access key");


  $customer_data = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM imp_customer_log WHERE updated_in_sib = '0'");
    foreach( $customer_data as $customer ) {

        $customer_id = $customer[0];
    $customer_event = $customer[1];
    $customer_data = $customer[2];
    $customer_sib = $customer[3];

        $user = get_user_by( 'id', $customer_id );
        $user_email = $user->user_email;

        $data = array(
            "email" => $user_email,
            "attributes" => array(
                $customer_event => $customer_data,
            ),
        );

        var_dump($mailin->create_update_user($data));
        // Change updated_in_sib to 1 for current row

  }
```

Comment: Are you asking what the sql for updating a row is, or are you asking for the PHP for run an update sql?

Comment: @Goose Sorry... php please

Comment: It appears you're using an ORM based on the code `$wpdb->get_results()`. Do you have a framework? Is it wordpress? Update the tags in your question and add more details and you'll likely get better answers from those qualified to answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i assume that this is a wordpress. you can use the update function in wpdb something look like this.

```
$wpdb->update('imp_customer_log', ['customer_sib' => 1], ['id' => $customer_id]);
```

you can check the it on documentation.  https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#UPDATE_rows

for php (not wordpress)

```
$sql = "UPDATE imp_customer_log SET customer_sib=1 WHERE id=" . $customer_id;
$connection->query($sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're using Wordpress. Take a look at these wordpress docs for update, used just like `get_results()` in your question.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/update/

```
$wpdb->update( string $table, array $data, array $where, array|string $format = null, array|string $where_format = null )
```